# How do I restrict access to a particular page in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, spuser

I want two pages from my site to be restricted from viewers until its contents are thoroughly checked by my team.

How do I accomplish this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the pages are in the pages library or any list, you can give item level permissions on them to restrict the user access.

Comment: Thank you, It worked. I placed the pages which I want to restrict on folder. I disable the "inherit permission" from this folder and edited the permission. I set  my team members to have full access while I disabled the permissions from the rest of the group. :D

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the publishing feature combined with the publishing workflow.
Look for **SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure** and **Publishing Approval Workflow** in SPSite (Site Collection) features.

This way you can have *approvers* being able to publish pages, and other will not see them.

Note that enabling the feature adds columns and similar which makes the site collection bound to publishing (even after disabling).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a workflow to manage content approval (also called moderation) in libraries with major and minor versioning enabled. When you use workflow to manage the content approval process, minor versions of a document remain in a pending state until they are approved or rejected through the workflow process.

Check this article for detailed steps:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/use-a-workflow-to-manage-content-approval-for-a-library-HA010172010.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Breaking permission inheritance at the item level is **not** a sustainable solution.

If these are Publishing pages then your drafts will only be visible by Contributors or higher level permission levels until you publish a major version.

Content Approval is an additional level of security that will restrict major versions from being published until someone with Approve permissions level approves the change.