# Sharepoint Permissions (Adding new members to site but don't want them to see/use certain quick links or access contents displayed there whatsoever)

Tags: permissions, navigation, access, item-level-permissions, pages

I created a team site that has a section for my team and a section for our business partners. These sections are comprised of several site pages and organized in an easily navigational fashion. IE. Business Partner section is made up of a 4 site pages (Type: Page Library) that are all displayed on the quick links navigation on the left. I also have a similar construct for items that should only be viewed by my team.

I want to add the business partners to the site but prevent them from seeing the finance pages and quick links.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To Restrict access on particular pages**:

Use **item level permissions** on site pages. Check below references for more information & steps:

1. [How do I restrict access to a particular page in SharePoint?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/46846/how-do-i-restrict-access-to-a-particular-page-in-sharepoint)
2. [How to set permissions on one page only in site?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/125116/how-to-set-permissions-on-one-page-only-in-site)
3. [SharePoint Groups and Page Level Permission in SharePoint 2013](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/746cd9/sharepoint-groups-and-page-level-permission-in-sharepoint-20/)
4. [How to prevent team site members from editing SharePoint pages](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-prevent-team-site-members-from-editing-sharepoint-pages/) - Check **Option 2** & set only **Read** permissions to specific set of people/groups & remove other permissions on specific page

**To Restrict from seeing quick links**:

If you are using SharePoint online, you can use Audience Targeting for Quick Links Web Part

More information at: [Audience Targeting for Quick Links Web Part in SharePoint Online](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/17/audience-targeting-for-quick-links-web-part-in-sharepoint-online/)