# Sharepoint List permission

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-permissions

I have created an spfx webpart for an SharePoint list. So here,

**I want everyone to have access to this list or the webpart page**, **without giving them access to the site**.

Can someone suggest me how can I achieve this.

Not everyone have access to the SharePoint site in my organization. Only Some users have access to the site.

Answer (score 1):

**For list**:

Break permissions inheritance from SharePoint site & then assign required permissions as per your requirements.

Check **Break permission inheritance in SharePoint** section at: [Customize permissions for a SharePoint list or library](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782)

**For web part page**:

Break permissions inheritance on particular page & then assign required permissions as per your requirements.

For more information: [Sharepoint Permissions (Adding new members to site but don't want them to see/use certain quick links or access contents displayed there whatsoever)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/293213/sharepoint-permissions-adding-new-members-to-site-but-dont-want-them-to-see-us/293216#293216)

Comment: Hi @Ganesh Sanap, I have done this already but still the users get "Sorry, You don't have access page". Just to be clear I want to give user access to the single page or list, without giving them access to the entire SharePoint site collection.

Comment: What permissions you assigned to users on list & page?

Comment: contribute permission

Comment: I have tried this at my end & it is working as expected. I even assigned **Read** (lower permissions) & it is working fine. Can you please check again?

Comment: Can you confirm that you removed user permission form the site collection and gave permission only to the list or the page? Is it possible to give permission to the list without giving permission to the site?

Comment: Yes. I have created a new user in tenant who don't have permissions on any subsite/site collection. Then I assigned permissions only on the single list & page. Maybe you can add the steps you followed to assign permissions to your original question by editing it (if possible, add screenshots, that will help). Also, when you assign permissions to users directly on lists, user will be added to site with **Limited Access** permissions. you can check this from site settings --> site permissions --> Check permissions.

Comment: Hi @priya Please check if your contribute permission level has been updated by someone and View Pages and View Application pages permissions are unchecked.

Comment: Hi, I tried all above steps with new site collection, it worked but with the existing site collection it still stays "no access". The existing sites were previously maintained by 3rd party and I don't know what I am missing in here.